# How to make ObjectMapper skip serialization of empty objects?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

The reason is that a consumer of my objects is a poor and legacy one that suffers from empty objects and throws `NPE`s and the only way to cope with it is to workaround on my side.

My application needs to skip serialization of empty objects.

```
class TopObject {
  NestedObject1 object1;
  NestedObject2 object2;
}
```

By default, if `object1` and `object2` both are null then `ObjectMapper` serializes `TopObject` as `{}`. Instead of it, I have to exclude the object from serialization at all.

Please note that

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
```

don't help in this case.

I believe that there must exist a relatively simple solution for it.

Could you please help me to sort it out?

Comment: Why can't you use Include.NON_NULL/Include.NON_EMPTY?

Comment: They doesn’t work for me

Comment: Moreover an object can consist of nested objects that are not null

Comment: Why not filter out the elements before serialization? You want to delegate crucial information / logic to your JSON-mapper, a simple `objects.filter(TopObject::isNotEmpty)` is more clear about what is happening and allows you to leave a comment for other developers why you are doing this